# moving subfolders in Microsoft Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook

is there a way to easily move multiple subfolders in outlook to another folder? drag and drop one at a time is way too slow. It doesn't work to try and highlight multiple folders to move either (shift or control key)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no built-in options in Outlook for us to move multiple folders at once. If you really would like this feature, may be you could try the add-in Diane mentioned in [this similar thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8-mso_2010/ways-to-bulk-select-move-multiple-folders-in/c787f2d2-9eee-4a3a-b12f-f11aaf23f6c4). Or you can try to vote in the [Outlook User voice](https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/19400881-move-multiple-folders-at-once-within-outlook-2016), Microsoft may notice it and add it in the later version.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful.